# Why is this CORS policy not working ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth-2.0, cors

I've been trying to set up Discord Oauth2 token authentication on an ASP.NET Core 2.2 / Angular 7 project and it has been quite a bumpy ride.

I'm using [this](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers)

I really can't seem to find any examples that give more than a fraction of the explanation required to set this all up. The error I'm currently battling with is the following:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://discordapp.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<removed>&scope=identify&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5000%2Fsignin-discord&state=<removed>'
(redirected from 'http://localhost:5000/api/v1/Authentication/SignIn') from origin 'http://localhost:5000' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

For context, here is some of my code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
            builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5000").AllowAnyHeader());
    });
    ...
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = DiscordAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = DiscordAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignOutScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "/login";
            options.LogoutPath = "/signout";
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        })
        .AddDiscord(options =>
        {
            options.ClientId = "<removed>";
            options.ClientSecret = "<removed>";
            options.Scope.Add("identify");
        });
    ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    ...
    app.UseCors("AllowAll");
    ...
}

// in AuthenticationController.cs
public class AuthenticationController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost("[action]")]
    public IActionResult SignIn()
    {
        return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties {RedirectUri = "http://localhost:5000"});
    }
    ...
}
```

## What i've been trying

I tried following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2#preflight-requests)

I tried all of these combinations of `services.addCors()` and `app.UseCors()` to no avail

```
services.AddCors();
app.UseCors(builder =>
   builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5000").AllowAnyHeader());

services.AddCors();
app.UseCors(builder =>
   builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
```

and everything inbetween. The error does not change no matter what I do with cors. Also, yes I have the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors` nu-get package installed. Yes, `app.UseCors()` is called before `app.useMvc`

Any other ideas?

Comment: Does adding `AllowAnyMethod` make a difference?

Comment: @John Unfortunately not, I have tried that

Comment: Is it definitely the CORS request against your API that's failing? Reading the message I'm not convinced it is. I could be wrong, of course.

Comment: I'm not sure. I just know that the error I'm getting is related to CORS blocking the request because of a missing header.

Comment: Yeah, it's saying that `discordapp.com` is refusing to allow *your* application running from `localhost:5000` to access it. It would be something to configure at the `discordapp.com` end, if they even allow `localhost` based apps to be authorized.

Comment: I expect you need to _redirect_ your web app to `http://localhost:5000/api/v1/Authentication/SignIn`, as opposed to making an XHR request to there.

Comment: _"I'm not sure."_ - look at the request in the network tab of your browser. I think it should tell you even for redirects.

Comment: I'm now seeing an error in the console: `Discord was not authenticated. Failure message: Not authenticated`. If the CORS error is thrown by discord, then it is probably as a result of this. I have all the credentials correct so i'm not sure what could be wrong there.

Comment: I now suspect that it has to do with the fact that the return uri specified in discord does not correspond with my app because it is hosted locally

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue today but figured it out later. Make sure you are using the same versions of net core. I happened to be using both 2.1 and 2.2 packages.